# Symplectic form on spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, integrable-systems

I have an exercise that says:

> calculate the symplectic form of 2-dimensional spheres with ratio r and let be H the height function, calculate the integrable system

I understand that for the symplectic form I need position and momentum but I don't know how to find the momentum without any physical model, and with other part I need some clue to start
Thanks for any helping

Comment: Did it occur to you to ask your professor or your classmates who are working on the same exercise?

Comment: I don't have classmates 'cause is a one person work, and I don't want arrive without anything to my professor